# How can I change my Velero credentials after they were reset

Tags: kubernetes, velero

I have an Azure Kubernetes cluster with Velero installed. A Service Principal was created for Velero, per [option 1 of the instructions](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure/tree/master#option-1-create-service-principal).

Velero was working fine until the credentials for the Service Principal were reset. Now the scheduled backups are failing.

```
NAME                                    STATUS      ERRORS   WARNINGS   CREATED                         EXPIRES   STORAGE LOCATION   SELECTOR
daily-entire-cluster-20210727030055     Failed      0        0          2021-07-26 23:00:55 -0000       13d       default            <none>
```

How can I update the secret for Velero?

Comment: Anything useful in `--secret-file ./credentials-velero`? It uses this location to start the `velero` - [install and start Velero](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure/tree/master#install-and-start-velero)

Comment: @moonkotte I have a secret file, but it looks like I can only use that option when installing. Doesn't seem to be a way to change the secrets. Re-install it is, I guess.

Comment: Another option is to check secrets in cluster if it's run within it. Otherwise it's a good case to reach out to Velero support. Sort of unlikely StackOverflow community will be able to answer question for them.

Comment: @moonkotte I was wrong -- it looks like the secret called `cloud-credentials` contains exactly the contents of the credentials file. I'll try to write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Update credentials file

First, update your credentials file (for most providers, this is `credentials-velero` and the contents are described in the plugin installation instructions: [AWS](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-aws#set-permissions-for-velero), [Azure](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure#create-service-principal), [GCP](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-gcp#option-1-set-permissions-with-a-service-account))

## 2. Update secret

Now update the velero secret. On linux:

```sh
kubectl patch -n velero secret cloud-credentials -p '{"data": {"cloud": "'$(base64 -w 0 credentials-velero)'"}}'
```

- `patch` tells `kubectl` to update a resource by merging the provided data
- `-n velero` tells `kubectl` to use the `velero` namespace
- `secret` is the resource type
- `cloud-credentials` is the name of the secret used by Velero to store credentials
- `-p`  specifies that the next word is the patch data. It's more common to patch using JSON rather than YAML
- `'{"data": {"cloud": "<your-base64-encoded-secret-will-go-here>"}}'` this is the JSON data that matches the existing structure of the Velero secret in Kubernetes. `<your-base64-encoded-secret-will-go-here>` is a placeholder for the command we'll insert.
- `$(base64 -w 0 credentials-velero)` reads the file `credentials-velero` in the current directory, turns off word wrapping of the output (`-w 0`), BASE64-encodes the contents of the file, and inserts the result in the data.